# Triggering m2e's UpdateProject action

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse

I am making my first steps in **Eclipse plugin development**. I wrote a small extension that triggers an action from the popup menu when a project in the project explorer is selected.

I am quite satisfied with the result because it automates an ennoying workflow which i had to perform repeatedly throughout the day.

Now, the icing on the cake would be if i could call the **m2e plugin's UpdateProject** action at the end of my implementation:

```
public class MyAction implements IObjectActionDelegate {

@Override
public void run(IAction action) {
    // .. doing something useful 
    PSEUDOCODE: M2eUtils.updateProject(action.getSelectedProject());
}
```

I did some research to figure out how to make it possible, but it seems to me i would have to dig deeper than i can afford at the moment to come to a solution on my own.

Any help is appreciated!